# What does it mean "One man with conviction is worth a hundred without"?

Tags: meaning

I new to the English language. I would be grateful if someone will help me to understand this sentences.

Comment: Hi Kadeer, and welome to ELL. While you have received a good answer to this questions, it's worth remembering that we generally hope that people will have made some effort to answer questions for themselves before asking here. That isn't to say I don't think you made such efforts - *conviction* has several senses and it can be hard to know which one applies. It would be helpful if you could mention what you've done to try to figure it out when you post a question, so we know where to start.

Comment: *One man with conviction (strongly-held beliefs) is **of equal value to** a hundred **men** without **conviction(s)**.*

Comment: A case where the difference between "conviction" and "a conviction" makes a huge difference!

Answer (score 2):

The word **[conviction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conviction)** means:

> a strong opinion or belief (about something)

In context, the speaker/ writer tries to convey that a person, who strongly believes in something, has more value, or requires more respect, than, say, hundred people who are not sure of the same thing (or something else).